# Can I change how frequently document versions are created?

Tags: sharepoint-online, versioning

I have several files (report drafts) located in a document library. Various teams collaborate on these documents continuously, meaning we blow through versions very quickly. Due to server space limitations, I would like to only keep 100-150 versions of these documents. Because we blow through versions quickly, it is common for teams to only have access to 2-3 days worth of versions.

Is it possible to change the frequency of version creation (e.g. 2-3 times per day) so that I can maintain a longer version history timeline with my existing server space?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it via **Library Settings** -> **Versioning settings** option.

There is a **Keep the following number of major versions** option which limits the number of major versions.

Alternatively, you can do major + minor versions and limit the minor versions, and users will need to **publish** the minor version when they are ready to upgrade to a major version

[image]